# Spring Security with WebSockets - Forbidden 403

Tags: spring, spring-security, stomp, spring-websocket, spring-messaging

I have implemented WebSocket in Spring. Everything worked fine, but recently I decided to implement Spring Security.

My MessageBroker looks like :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
@Component("messageBroker")
public class MessageBroker implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry stompEndpointRegistry) {
        stompEndpointRegistry.addEndpoint("/graphs").withSockJS();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry messageBrokerRegistry) {
    }

    @Override
    public void configureClientInboundChannel(ChannelRegistration channelRegistration) {
    }

    @Override
    public void configureClientOutboundChannel(ChannelRegistration channelRegistration) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean configureMessageConverters(List<MessageConverter> messageConverters) {
        messageConverters.add(new MappingJackson2MessageConverter());
        return false;
    }

}
```

And my JS client looks liks this :

```
var socket = new SockJS('/server/graphs');
var client = Stomp.over(socket);

client.connect({}, function (frame) {
    client.subscribe("/data", function (message) {
        console.log('GET MESSAGE :' + message.body);
        var test = JSON.parse(message.body);
        var point = [ (new Date()).getTime(), parseInt(25) ];
        var shift = randomData.data.length > 60;
        randomData.addPoint(point, true, shift);
    });

});
```

Spring Security Config :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

    <security:http auto-config='true' use-expressions="true" disable-url-rewriting="true">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/login/**" access="isAnonymous()"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/index/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/volumegraph/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/graphs/**" access="permitAll()" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/graphs/**/**" access="permitAll()" />
        <security:form-login login-page="/" login-processing-url="/" authentication-failure-url="/" always-use-default-target="true"/>
        <security:csrf/>
        <security:logout logout-success-url="/login"/>
        <security:headers>
            <security:frame-options></security:frame-options>
        </security:headers>
    </security:http>

    <security:authentication-manager>
        <security:authentication-provider>
            <security:user-service>
                <security:user name="user" password="password" authorities="ROLE_USER"/>
            </security:user-service>
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>

</beans>
```

After subscribing via my JS client I receive :

```
Opening Web Socket...
sockjs.js:1213 WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8080/server/graphs/651/kyzdihld/websocket' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404
sockjs.js:807 POST http://localhost:8080/server/graphs/651/zx7zdre7/xhr_streaming 403 (Forbidden)AbstractXHRObject._start @ sockjs.js:807(anonymous function) @ sockjs.js:834
sockjs.js:807 POST http://localhost:8080/server/graphs/651/o6eg5ikc/xhr 403 (Forbidden)AbstractXHRObject._start @ sockjs.js:807(anonymous function) @ sockjs.js:834
stomp.js:122 Whoops! Lost connection to undefined
```

So I decided to add this code in Security Config :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

<security:websocket-message-broker>
    <!--<security:intercept-message pattern="/graphs/**" access="permitAll()"/>-->
    <security:intercept-message pattern="/**" access="permitAll()"/>
    <security:intercept-message type="SUBSCRIBE" access="permitAll()"/>
    <security:intercept-message type="CONNECT" access="permitAll()"/>
</security:websocket-message-broker>

</beans>
```

but after that I receive this kind of error :

```
NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'springSecurityMessagePathMatcher' is defined
```

I do not know how define such bean, so I created this below class :

```
@Configuration
public class WebSocketSecurityConfig extends AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    protected void configureInbound(MessageSecurityMetadataSourceRegistry messages) {
        messages.simpDestMatchers("/graphs/*").permitAll();
        messages.simpDestMatchers("/**").permitAll();
    }
}
```

But during compilation I receive this kind of error :

```
java: cannot access org.springframework.beans.factory.SmartInitializingSingleton
  class file for org.springframework.beans.factory.SmartInitializingSingleton not found
```

and I really do not know how to fix this :( I must to add that I am using Spring Core 4.0.1.RELEASE and Spring Messaging 4.0.1.RELEASE. All libs related with Spring Security is in version 4.0.1.RELEASE.

Comment: is your MessageBroker class's package is in for component scan ?

Comment: If you are using @EnableCaching is a bug https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12336, that give SmartInitializingSingleton not found. Can you upload full error

Comment: I did not use @EnableCaching

Comment: @Jebil Yes i think that it is. You can see there https://github.com/GarciaPL/CurrencyFair/blob/master/currencyfair/currencyfair-consumer/src/main/resources/currencyfair-consumer-ctx.xml but it is not this case. This app is modificated in such way to not use security for MessageBroker

Comment: It seems like you haven't added `currencyfair-consumer-ctx.xml` into your 'web.xml', also it is in the resources folder, not in `WEB-INF`. 
Check with that and I think issue is there.

Comment: In web.xml you can find root-consumer-ctx.xml which includes currencyfair-consumer-ctx.xml. https://github.com/GarciaPL/CurrencyFair/blob/master/currencyfair/currencyfair-consumer/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/root-consumer-ctx.xml

Comment: Have you tried to to add in first xml  to ```<security:http>``` ```<security:intercept-url pattern="/server/graphs/**" access="permitAll()" />``` ? Btw ```<security:intercept-url pattern="/graphs/**" access="permitAll()" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/graphs/**/**" access="permitAll()" />```  - you don't need the second pattern, because '/graphs/**' ant match already takes it and it is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get this to work you have to modify your `<security:websocket-message-broker >` **by adding some id to it**, `<security:websocket-message-broker  id="interceptor">` and link it to the definition of your websocket Inbound channels.

```
<websocket:message-broker  application-destination-prefix="/app" user-destination-prefix="/user" >
 <websocket:stomp-endpoint path="/websocketEndPoint" >
 <websocket:handshake-handler ref="astalavista" />
 <websocket:simple-broker prefix="/topic , /queue"  /> 
 <websocket:client-inbound-channel >
   <websocket:interceptors>
   <!--This will reference your interceptor that you have defined in you security XML-->
      <ref bean="interceptor"/>
   </websocket:interceptors>
 </websocket:client-inbound-channel>
</websocket:message-broker>
```